# Remove cosmetic margins from edge of TextEdit window?

Tags: macos, applications, high-sierra, textedit

Just opened TextEdit today and I see these strange margins:

[image]

They *kinda* look like rulers only without the actual measurements, but turning off rulers doesn't make them go away.

What are these, and how do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 5):

## Scroll Bars

These are scroll bars. You can turn them off in the **System Settings** > **Appearance** panel:

[image]

Comment: +1 for reading between the lines (so to speak;). I'm so used to permanent scroll bars that I wasn't even seeing them as part of the issue.

Comment: Ahhh it all makes sense now. This morning was the first time I plugged a traditional mouse into one of my Macs.

Comment: Good to hear this helped. The scroll bar visibility changes depending on input devices connected to your Mac. Plugging in a mouse can change the look of window's scroll bars.